# Software Crash; Error setting path: "rfPersonal"

Tags: path, crash, runtime-error, root, game-maker

I have the Pro version of Gamemaker Studio, and it has worked for months, but recently it started throwing this message and failing to open. I have tried everything from restarting, reinstalling, installing different builds, clearing `%appdata%`, and even resetting the PC. Nothing seems to fix it.

[image: error message]

I can't find any resolved issues with an `rfPersonal` routing, only a few mentioning having it. I'm bashing my head against the keyboard trying to figure this out!

Does anyone know what the `rfPersonal` route is, why it may have broken, and/or how to set it back through the root file in any way?

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same issue launching GameMakerStudio. I discovered that the Studio would only launch successfully when I was connected to my network at work or VPN connected from home. I'm assuming that GameMakerStudio is trying to read or write to one of my personal folder locations, like the AppData folder, and that my personal folder locations are assigned to a mapped drive that can only be found when I am connected to my workplace network.
Hope that helps.

Jones